# Typescript error in ReactJS tests with React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

I'm using ReactJS and Material UI and Typescript. I want to test my menu - should show after I click on button with label `Location`. New menu should contain `Location 1` item.

```
describe('<LocationsMenu />', () => {
    let component: RenderResult;

    beforeEach(() => {
        component = render(<LocationsMenu />);
    });

    it('should show and hide on click on top item trigger', async () => {
        const button = component.getByText('Locations').parentElement;
        await act(async () => {
            fireEvent.click(button);
        });
        expect(component.getByText('Location 1')).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

This works - test passes.

Visual Studio Code shows me error in `fireEvent.click(button)` line: `Argument of type 'HTMLElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Element | Node | Document | Window'.`. How can I avoid it? I know I can do type casting like:

```
fireEvent.click(button as Element);
```

or

```
const button = component.getByText('Locations').parentElement as Element;
```

But maybe there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript can deduce your variable type at any position in the source file, you need to 'cast' the button to `HTMLElement` instead of `HTMLElement | null` by checking if it's not `null`

```js
// button may be null
const button = component.getByText('Locations').parentElement;

if (button) {
  // at this point, typescript knows that button cannot be null
  // so it has HTMLElement type in the block
  fireEvent.click(button);
}
```

Also note that I don't wrap [`fireEvent.click()`](https://testing-library.com/docs/preact-testing-library/api#fireevent) inside `act()`. It's because `react-testing-library` has already done that for you so it's unnecessary here.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is brevity and you are absolutely sure the the element exists or the test would failed otherwise, you can ensure typescript by adding a *non-null assertion operator* like this

```js
// button may be null, but you say it's not
const button = component.getByText('Locations').parentElement!;

fireEvent.click(button);
```